# Using rvest to scrape across multiple web pages in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to R and have been doing some web scraping. I have written the following code which will place the ID, name, colour and price of a specific item from https://uk.burberry.com/ into a data frame.

```
# load package
library(rvest)

# Example URL
url <- 'https://uk.burberry.com/fringed-wool-cashmere-patchwork-cardigan-coat-p40612561'

# Read HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)

# using css selectors to scrape the ID section
id_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '.section') 
#converting the ID to text
id_data <- html_text(id_data_html)
# Remove irrelevant text
id_data <- gsub("Item", "", id_data)

# using css selectors to scrape the names section
names_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '.type-h6') 
#converting the names to text
names_data <- html_text(names_data_html)
# Stripping irrelevant text
names_data <- gsub("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "", names_data)

# using css selectors to scrape the price section
price_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '.l2') 
#converting the price to text
price_data <- html_text(price_data_html)
# Remove irrelevant text
price_data <- gsub("\t", "", price_data)
price_data <- gsub("\n", "", price_data)

# using css selectors to scrape the colour section
colour_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '#colour-picker-value') 
#converting the colour to text
colour_data <- html_text(colour_data_html)

# creating the dataframe
burberry_df <- data.frame(ID = id_data, Name = names_data, Price = price_data, Colour = colour_data)
```

Is there a way to create a loop so I can use this code for every item on the website and put the results in a data frame? Thanks

Comment: _"1.4 … Subject to the terms herein, we grant you a revocable, and non-exclusive licence to access and make personal use of the Platforms limited such that it does not include the right to: … (c) use software robots, spiders, crawlers, or similar data gathering and extraction tools…"_. Please at least indicate when you're asking others to violate ToS and incur possible legal or civil actions against them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function which accepts an input URL and returns a data frame with the information collected from the webpage:

```
get_page_data <- function(url) {
    # Read HTML code from the website
    webpage <- read_html(url)

    # using css selectors to scrape the ID section
    id_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '.section') 
    #converting the ID to text
    id_data <- html_text(id_data_html)
    # Remove irrelevant text
    id_data <- gsub("Item", "", id_data)

    # using css selectors to scrape the names section
    names_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '.type-h6') 
    #converting the names to text
    names_data <- html_text(names_data_html)
    # Stripping irrelevant text
    names_data <- gsub("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t", "", names_data)

    # using css selectors to scrape the price section
    price_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '.l2') 
    #converting the price to text
    price_data <- html_text(price_data_html)
    # Remove irrelevant text
    price_data <- gsub("\t", "", price_data)
    price_data <- gsub("\n", "", price_data)

    # using css selectors to scrape the colour section
    colour_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage, '#colour-picker-value') 
    #converting the colour to text
    colour_data <- html_text(colour_data_html)

    # creating the dataframe
    burberry_df <- data.frame(ID = id_data, Name = names_data, Price = price_data,
                              Colour = colour_data)

    return(burberry_df)
}
```

Then to use the function simply call it while passing the URL of interest:

```
url <- 'https://uk.burberry.com/fringed-wool-cashmere-patchwork-cardigan-coat-p40612561'
result <- get_page_data(url)
```